# Keeps prepending several images

Tags: jquery, sharepoint, each, prepend

I'm working on SharePoint with jQuery and each time I use the prepend() function in combination with the each() function in order to display a image before each cell in a list, I get several of those images.

More specifically, the amount of those images matchs the amount of items in the list. I bet that's a clue to what's going on, but I'm no jQuery expert

Here is a piece of code:

```
$(item).each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).prepend(image); 
});
```

Image, btw, `image` is a variable that contains html code for an image. `Item` is this:

```
var item = #MSO_ContentTable td.ms-vb2>div:has(>div);
```

This place is awesome!

Comment: This doesn't even make any sense. Where's the problem/question?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
$(item).each(function(i, e) {
  $(e).prepend(image[i]); 
});
```

But I'm unclear on what `image` is, if it's a set of elements, it'll prepend to set to each match the `item` selector finds.  If it's a jQuery element or an array, the above will work, if it's something else, please post it.

The above example takes the matching `image` entry and prepends it to the current `item` match of the same index, that's the best I can gather from the question as it was asked.

Comment: It didn't work.
"image" contains html and that is all. It's not an array, just a single entity that I want to place before all the "items". Sorry for the vagueness.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem may lie in the selector for `item`. It's been my experience that SharePoint-generated HTML contains a lot of "empty" elements that, while not visible in the rendered page, are picked up by jQuery queries.

I find Mozilla Firefox and Firebug indispensable when crafting jQuery selectors. Here's what I suggest:

1. Get [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/) and [Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843/) (if you haven't already)
2. Open your SharePoint page in FF and hit f12 to activate FB
3. In FB, switch to the Console tab (you may need to select "Enabled" from the Console drop-down menu first)
4. On the line at the bottom of the Console (denoted by `>>>`), type in your jQuery:
   `jQuery("#MSO_ContentTable td.ms-vb2>div:has(>div)")`
5. Hit Return; The Console's output window should show you all the matches represented by the selector. Hover your mouse over each one to see it highlighted in the page.

By using this technique, you can see if your queries pull back too many, too few or not at all the right results.

Be sure to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in the FB console window, as the dollar-alias is also used by FB.

Good luck!